# Show $n^{-1} \max_{k\leq n} X_k \rightarrow 0 \quad a.s.$ if and only if $\mathbb{E}(X_1)_+<\infty$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_1>-\infty)>0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Show that $$n^{-1} \max_{k\leq n} X_k \rightarrow 0 \quad a.s.$$ if and only if $\mathbb{E}(X_1)_+<\infty$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_1>-\infty)>0$

Hoping for a hint on where to start.

Comment: The statement about $P(X_1>-\infty)$ is incomplete.

Comment: You need to add that $X_{n}$ takes value on the extended real line.

Answer (score 2):

First, show that $(X_n)_+/n\to 0$ a.s. if and only if $E(X_1)_+<\infty$, using Borel-Cantelli, and the layer cake representation $E(X_1)_+\approx \sum_n P(X_1>n)$.

Second, show that $(X_n)_+/n\to 0$ a.s. if and only if $\tilde M_n/n\to 0$ a.s, where $\tilde M_n=\max_{k\le n} (X_k)_+$. This is a general fact about sequences: if $x_n\ge 0 $ is a deterministic sequence where $x_n/n\to 0$, then $\frac1n \max_{k\le n} x_k\to 0$ as well.

Finally, consider how $\tilde M_n$ and $M_n\equiv\max_{k\le n} X_n$ are related. If $X_1$ has any positive probability of being nonnegative, then $\tilde M_n=M_n$ eventually with probability 1. If $X_1<0$ a.s, then you can directly prove that $M_n/n\to 0$ a.s.

Comment: I don't quite understand your last part, how does this argument incorporate with the condition $P(X_{1}>-\infty)>0?$